# How to use sprof?

Tags: linux, sprof

please explain with example?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838989/gprof-how-to-generate-call-graph-for-functions-in-shared-library-that-is-linked/4959168#4959168

Answer (score 8):

From the emails found [here](http://sources.redhat.com/ml/libc-alpha/2003-07/msg00029.html) and [here](http://sourceware.org/ml/binutils/2002-04/msg00035.html), I've extracted the following notes:

Given an application `my_app', which links against a shared object`my_sobj', and has been compiled with the '-g' compile flag:

```
#set the environment variable LD_PROFILE to the name of the shared obj
export LD_PROFILE=my_obj
#run your application
my_app
#this should create a file /var/tmp/my_sobj.profile
#now run sprof
sprof my_sobj my_sobj.profile
```

This gives profile information for the shared library, not for my_app

Comment: does this only work for libc stuff?  Or can I use it on my own compiled shared libraries?

Comment: "no PLTREL found in object" is the error I get when trying to profile my own library.  What do I need to do at compile/link time to include the required information?