# gprof : How to generate call graph for functions in shared library that is linked to main program

Tags: c, debugging, profiling, gprof, sprof

I am working on Linux environment. I have two 'C' source packages train and test_train.

1. train package when compiled generates libtrain.so
2. test_train links to libtrain.so and generates executable train-test

Now I want to generate a call graph using gprof which shows calling sequence of functions in main program as well as those inside libtrain.so

I am compiling and linking both packages with -pg option and debugging level is o0.
After I do ./train-test , gmon.out is generated. Then I do:

```
$ gprof -q ./train-test gmon.out
```

Here, output shows call graph of functions in train-test but not in libtrain.so

What could be the problem ?

Answer (score 28):

`gprof` won't work, you need to use `sprof` instead.  I found these links helpful:

- [How to use sprof?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881074/how-to-use-sprof)
- http://greg-n-blog.blogspot.com/2010/01/profiling-shared-library-on-linux-using.html

Summary from the 2nd link:

1. Compile your shared library (libmylib.so) in debug (-g) mode. No -pg.
2. export LD_PROFILE_OUTPUT=`pwd`
3. export LD_PROFILE=libmylib.so
4. rm -f $LD_PROFILE.profile
5. execute your program that loads libmylib.so
6. sprof PATH-TO-LIB/$LD_PROFILE $LD_PROFILE.profile -p >log
7. See the log.

I found that in step 2, it needs to be an existing directory -- otherwise you get a helpful warning.  And in step 3, you might need to specify the library as `libmylib.so.X` (maybe even `.X.Y`, not sure) -- otherwise you get no warning whatsoever.

Comment: Its worth noting that often you can work out what the name of the library your binary is trying to load (mylib.so vs mylib.so.1 vs mylib.so.1.1 etc) by running `ldd` on the application. This should only not have an entry if the library is getting opened via a direct dlopen call.

Comment: too bad sprof crashes quite badly, as in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216979/what-is-causing-sprof-to-complain-about-inconsistency-detected-by-ld-so)

Comment: What if sprof doesn't come in with MinGW, the compiler chosen for my project ?

Comment: After running program that loaded library, ran sprof and got this error: "Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-open.c: 635: _dl_open: Assertion `_dl_debug_initialize (0, args.nsid)->r_state == RT_CONSISTENT' failed!"

Answer (score 3):

I'm loading my library from Python and didn't have any luck with `sprof`. Instead, I used `oprofile`, which was in the Fedora repositories, at least:

> `operf --callgraph /path/to/mybinary`
>
> Wait for your application to finish or do Ctl-c to stop profiling. Now let's generate a profile summary:
>
> `opreport --callgraph --symbols`

See the [documentation](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/doc/opreport.html) to interpret it. It's kind of a mess. In the generated report, each symbol is listed in a block of its own. The block's main symbol is the one that's not indented. The items above it are functions that call that function, and the ones below it are the things that get called by it. The percentages in the below section are the relative amount of time it spent in those callees.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not on Linux (like me on Solaris) you simply out of luck as there is no `sprof` there. 
If you have the sources of your library you can solve your problem by linking a static library and making your profiling binary with that one instead.
Another way I manage to trace calls to shared libraries, is by using `truss`. With the option `-u [!]lib,...:[:][!]func, ...` one can get a good picture of the call history of a run. It's not completely the same as profiling but can be very usefull in some scenarios.