# How to profile Native JNI library

Tags: java, c, jvm, java-native-interface, profiling

How can I profile a Java Native Interface  library written in C?

I know about the usual C profilers, but my question is how can I profile the ***whole*** set including the calls to the JVM methods which might be slowing down the program.

Comment: What platform OS? If you can run on OS-X or Solaris, dtrace can provide an integrated view, profiling across the JVM, OS user space, and into the kernel.

Comment: Currently GNU/Linux. Also to specify I'm talking about performance in terms of CPU. Not memory issues.

Comment: dtrace isn't a memory profiler, if that's what the second half of your comment was directed at.

Comment: No, no. It was just to clarify my initial question. I will see if I can find somewhere to run dtrace but let's see if there's another way. Thanks!

Comment: It seems Oracle does make it available for Linux now, though since it comes from Oracle, I have no idea of the terms: https://blogs.oracle.com/linux/entry/announcement_dtrace_for_oracle_linux

Comment: You mentioned that you know about "the usual C profilers"-- does that include OProfile? ( http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/ ) I have obtained useful results when using this for profiling multiple different components operating together on a Linux system.

Comment: No, I didn't consider OProfile, but thanks for pointing that out! I did indeed take a look into it but finally I ended up using `sprof`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some research and testing with some of the methods proposed here I ended up using `sprof`.

Basically I followed the instructions available [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4959168/838642). Some comments:

1. I had to leave `LD_PROFILE_OUTPUT` empty in order to get the result in `/var/tmp/`, otherwise the output file was not generated.
2. I assigned `LD_PROFILE=libXXXX.so`

To get the profile I ran the Java code which loads and uses the native JNI library and I got a file with the profiling results in:

`/var/tmp/libXXXX.so.profile`

Once you have the file you can read it using the command:

`sprof /path/to/libXXXX.so /var/tmp/libXXXX.so.profile`

The results of the profiling follow the same template as `gprof`. [Here](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/as/gprof_toc.html) you can find a description of the contents and their meaning.

Comment: Hey , could I ask you more on this one? Did you run the javacode from command line where you exported all the variables , or did you do it from eclipse ?

Comment: I run into `Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-open.c: 717: _dl_open: Assertion '_dl_debug_initialize (0, args.nsid)->r_state == RT_CONSISTENT' failed!` which i fail to resolve...