# JNI library profiling

Tags: java, java-native-interface, profiling

in my project I wrote a java-agent library, which i want to profile. This question was already asked in 2013 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14752459/how-to-profile-native-jni-library). So, I tried following the suggestion, using sprof, which failed due to [this problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/944169/sprof-fails-to-generate-flat-profiling-for-my-shared-library-inconsistency-dete). I have also tried oprofile, however I am still not able to identify the bottlenecks of my application from its output.

So, my question is, what are the other suitable profilers for java native libraries? Does anyone have expirience in this kind of task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should choose "Hotspots and stacks" while you're configuring analysis. See screenshot below. When collection is done that you should switch to the "Top-down Tree" tab in VTune UI. More info about the "Top-down Tree" tab is [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/vtune-amplifier-help-window-top-down-tree).
Try to use "Hotspots, call count and stacks" to get call counts.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You may find useful [VTune Amplifier](https://software.intel.com/en-us/vtune) which is a profiler supporting [Java code analysis](https://software.intel.com/en-us/vtune-amplifier-help-java-code-analysis). You will be able to see the hotspots in your Java code and the performance metrics distributed through your java source file. What's really valuable is that VTune Amplifier shows the accurate stacks for pure Java code and Java/C++ mixed mode code. Please ask if you have questions.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. However i am less interested in profiling java code. Instead, I want to profile the code of my C++ java-agent. Do you think it is possible with the VTune?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It should work for your case. The only thing you should do while you are configure analysis  with VTune is to switch the mrte-mode from Auto to Native to say Vtune not to load its Java agent, than start profiling. Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: So i have install VTune_Amplifier and am able to run it. Is there a way to view the profiling results as a callgraph?

Comment: is there a way to get actual call counts for each method? I couldnt see that in the Advanced Hotspots mode Top-Down-Tree view